# VS2012 Crystal Report Viewer Group Tree Hide

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

Asp.Net. Webform with a CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0 CrystalReportsViewer.

I want to hide / disable the L.H. Pane containing the Group Tree Button.

The DisplayGroupTree property is marked as obsolete and has no effect.

I have set ToolPanelView="None" that also has no effect.

The hiding of Group Tree problem has existed from earlier versions but published answers do not work or translate to this version as far as I can see.

Maybe I am building the report wrong. (it displays OK).

```
 private void ShowReport(MyClassLibrary.Report report)
    {
        ConnectionInfo cn = new ConnectionInfo();
        cn.ServerName = "MyServer";
        cn.DatabaseName = "MyDatabase";
        cn.UserID = "myUser";
        cn.Password = "myPassword";
        string reportDirectory = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Reports\\";
        CrystalReportSource rs = new CrystalReportSource();
        Session["CurrentReportSource"] = rs;
        CrystalDecisions.Web.Report r = new CrystalDecisions.Web.Report();


        r.FileName = reportDirectory + report.reportPath;
        rs.Report = r;

        CRV.ReportSource = rs;



        ParameterFields p = CRV.ParameterFieldInfo;
        ParameterField pUserId = new ParameterField();
        pUserId.Name = "@user_id";
        ParameterField pStartDate = new ParameterField();
        pStartDate.Name = "@start_date";
        ParameterField pEndDate = new ParameterField();
        pEndDate.Name = "@end_date";

        ParameterDiscreteValue pUserIdValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pStartDateValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue pEndDateValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today - t;
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;
        //**LIVE CODE***
        //CouponUser user = (CouponUser) Session["CurrentUser"];
        //pUserId_Value.Value = user.userId;
        //***TEST CODE***
        pUserIdValue.Value = 2;
        //********
        pStartDateValue.Value = startDate;
        pEndDateValue.Value = endDate;


        pUserId.CurrentValues.Add(pUserIdValue);
        pStartDate.CurrentValues.Add(pStartDateValue);
        pEndDate.CurrentValues.Add(pEndDateValue);

        p.Add(pUserId);
        p.Add(pStartDate);
        p.Add(pEndDate);


        foreach (TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo in CRV.LogOnInfo)
        {
            logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = cn;
        }


        rs.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

try 
To Turn off:

```
CrystalReportViewer.ToolPanelView = ToolPanelViewType.None
```

To Turn on:

```
CrystalReportViewer.ToolPanelView = ToolPanelViewType.GroupTree
```

group button will appear in both

Answer (score 3):

Bob,

have you tried the HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" property? I believe that will get rid of the button and the panel.

Give it a try and let me know if it works.

Chris

Comment: Hi Chris, tried this, it takes no notice. I am thinking that maybe my environment is wrong. When I click on one of the group tree entries the report collapses to a single line holding 'ERROR' I threw a Winform application together and that was able to display and drill on this report OK. Due to the difference in the CR objects about the only thing I can take out of that is the WinForm is hanging a ReportDocument in the viewer where as the Webform is hanging a Report object. Unless you have any better ideas I will rework the webform logic and try to get it using a ReportDocument object.

Comment: ReportDocument appears to be not available under CrystalDecisions.Web so it seems the Report object is the correct one to use.

Comment: Bob, just for clarification, when you say Webform, do you mean a ASP.NET Web Application? And a WinForm is a Windows Form?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes. I reinstalled the SAP Visual Studio. Found that to use ReportDocument object needed to reference Crystal Reports Engine. Did that and converted the logic over to 'Report Document'. Still faulty. I am building a new Web App project with an internal report and see where that leads. Shall report back. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Sounds good, Bob. Hope you can get it figured out but will be glad to try and help you out if I can.

Comment: Hi Chris, had a battle deploying the new build with CR to the production machine, when the dust settled I went back to this problem and suddenly it works. No Side bar. The trick was attributes ToolPanelView="None" and HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" both being declared. Thanks again. Bob.

Comment: That's great news, Bob! I'm glad that you got it working and that I was at least partially right!  ;o)

Answer (score 3):

```
controlname.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
controlname.ShowGroupTreeButton = False
controlname.ShowParameterPanelButton = False
```

Comment: Please don't just post code as an answer - edit your answer to leave a bit of text explaining _why_ this code solves the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it by this statment:

```
crystalReportsViewer.ToggleSidePanel = SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.Constants.SidePanelKind.None;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to close group tree and hide its button within my viewers .xaml file.  I use CR for Visual Studio 2015 and have this line within my Grid tags

```
 <cr:CrystalReportsViewer Name="ReportViewer"  ToggleSidePanel="None" ShowToggleSidePanelButton="False" ShowStatusbar="False" ShowLogo="False"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

The ToggleSidePanel = None sets the items displayed to none
The ShowToggleSidePanelButton = False hides the button so that the tree cannot be viewed at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer x:Name="BillViewer" ToggleSidePanel="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the TreeView with HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" and ToolPanelView="None"

```
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True"
            Height="50px"
            Visible="False" Width="350px" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="False" EnableParameterPrompt="False" DisplayToolbar="False" SeparatePages="False" EnableDrillDown="False"
            HasDrilldownTabs = "False"
            HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false"
ToolPanelView="None"/>
```